# How Can I Trim a string in dart as i want

Tags: string, dart

I have the following string https://www.something.com/api/mmmm/media/mhm/something.jpg and I want to trim this string to become  https://www.something.com/media/mhm/something.jpg essentially I want it to be dynamic so I don't want to hardcode it because the URL won't be the same forever this particular part will change. Put it another way I want to remove everything from /api/ till it reaches to /media/ and I don't seem to be able to do it.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `Uri.parse` to parse the url and the loop the pathSegments of the uri create a new uri with the pathSegments that you mish to keep, such as:

```
void main() {
  var uri =
      Uri.parse('https://www.something.com/api/mmmm/media/mhm/something.jpg');

  var exclude = false;
  var newPath = <String>[];
  for (var seg in uri.pathSegments) {
    if (seg == 'api') {
      exclude = true;
      continue;
    }
    if (seg == 'media') {
      exclude = false;
    }
    if (!exclude) {
      newPath.add(seg);
    }
  }
  var newUri = uri.replace(pathSegments: newPath);
  print(newUri); //Prints https://www.something.com/media/mhm/something.jpg
}
```

Answer (score 1):

An alternative solution would be use a RegExp like this:

```
void main() {
  print(
      trimString('https://www.something.com/api/mmmm/media/mhm/something.jpg'));
  // https://www.something.com/media/mhm/something.jpg

  print(trimString(
      'https://www.something.com/api/AlotOfStrangeThings/complateNonsense/&&&&&/media/mhm/something.jpg'));
  // https://www.something.com/media/mhm/something.jpg
}

String trimString(String string) =>
    string.replaceAll(RegExp(r'/api/(.*)/media/'), '/media/');
```

Comment: Thank you all i really appreciate it!